# Have unique constraint between tables

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I need to validate uniqueness of an element but each element could have `n` codes and I need to validate that to. Element should be unique by type, provider, time and code. When an element is created it has a code array if any of that codes overlap with existing element code that means the element is the same.

E.g Having

codes

```html
| id     | code|
|:-------| ---:| 
| 1      | 123 | 
| 2      | 456 |
```

elements

```html
| id     | type          | provider_id  | time       |
|:-------|:-------------:| ------------:|-----------:|
| 1      | A             | 1            | 01/01/2016 |
```

codes_elements

```html
| code_id | element_id  |
|:--------|------------:| 
| 1       | 1           |
```

Expectations:

When I try to insert:

```
`Element = type: A, provider: 1, codes: [1], time: 01/01/2015`
```

I expect this fails because violate contrain

When I try to insert:

```
`Element = type: B, provider: 1, codes: [1], time: 01/01/2015`
```

I expect this create a new element with code relation

When I try to insert:

```
`Element = type: A, provider: 1, codes: [2], time: 01/01/2015`
```

I expect this create a new element because element is the same but the code array not overlap with any other element

When I try to insert:

```
`Element = type: A, provider: 1, codes: [1, 2], time: 01/01/2015`
```

I expect this add relation in codes_elements only so element 1 will have 2 codes now because code 1 overlap other element which means that this is same element so I need to just include code 2

Options that I see

- Change join table to int array in elements table.- In this case I can search by other columns and append code id also create contrain by codes array to prevent duplication. Problem with this is when I query element table by code is slow e.g get all elements with code 1.
- Create a trigger and check if codes overlap other element assign just code relation if not create new element.

I'm using Ruby on Rails but I need model validations are not enought because I've multiple threads doing inserts at same time and could end with duplications

I would like to know better options or comments about current ideas looking improve performance, prevent duplication, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to set the validation in RoR?

If the element is repeated you are going to have an error message anyway. You can rise and handle the error in RoR adding a character like "1"to the end of the element if it is repeated. Other option is create a "consolidate" column in the codes_elements table and save the element+code value in it.

EDIT:

You can be sure about not to save duplicated rows using a transaction:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   elements.code do |c|
     Element.find_or_create_by(code: c, element: e)
    or
     Element.exists? code: c, element: e
   end
end
```

Comment: OP said that he has multiple threads and active record doesn't prevent race conditions.